# Facilitated menu setup in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I want to have it so that when desktop QGIS icon is selected, to open QGIS, that I can based on script running after that select different project set-up when it comes to menu and Tabs set-up. Less or more tabs in an initial project.

What are the general steps of how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit confuse and difficult to understand. Can you make your point clearer?

Comment: Are you looking for user profile ? (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles)

Answer (score 3):

### To change menus

See the [official doc about customization](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#customization) for menus

### To change toolbars,

Use the Python plugin ["Customize ToolBars"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CustomToolBar/) (available in official default plugins repository)

### Switch profiles

With above help, you will be able to customize QGIS GUI. You now will need to switch between configuration. You can do it with [the user profiles](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles)

To make it happen at startup, you may copy the icon from the GUI and then change some parameters from qgis when executing it e.g below clues:

```
# mycustom.ini is the ini file saved from "Settings" > "Interface Customization", ticked "Enable customization" and then "Save to file"
qgis --customizationfile mycustom.ini
```

```
# To load a profile
qgis --profile default
```

Comment: hi, does your explanation include that every time i open QGIS i have two options to get project setup when it ocmes to Menus and Toolbars 1. to load customization file(.ini) or 2. that i have under Settings -User profiles a specific profile that  sets-up Menus and toolbars for each different user. Is it so that is supposed to work.

Comment: Is something similar achievable directly by double click  on QGIS desktop icon (Qgis.exe) and selecting on a window which pop-ups from there  and there are shown different user profiles to select from with different project Menu and toolb. setup?